# where in database is renamed login for 'Rename Admin Paths"

Tags: 8, database

A little embarrassing - I've lost/forgotten the login page for a Drupal 8.9 website. It was renamed using the module "Rename Admin Paths."

I've gone to the module page at drupal.org and looked through issues and comments, but none of the solutions I found will work.

This site is unable to install Composer or Drush at this time, so I can't use any method there. Another suggestion was to search the 'variables' table - but that was specific to D7, I believe. I don't see that table.

I've commented within their page hoping to find the answer, but maybe someone here happens to know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `config` and `key_value` tables for "rename_admin_paths.settings"

Comment: hmm.. Was able to find the fields, but they're in the system as a blob. I was able to view the blob through 'options' in phpmyadmin, and export the rows, but it's just a long, long string of characters. No idea how to translate that into a readable value

Comment: I typically see the information as a serialized array. Without doing any sort of export, see if phpMyAdmin has an option to view the blob as text. Some quick Googling on my part indicates that's possible.